# Splitting method for time series

Tags: time-series, distance-functions

Say I have a website with a lot of pages and traffic. Some of them are more visited, some of them a less. My task is to split pages into two groups for the given time period, so that the total traffic going to these groups is as similar as possible (day-wise). Could you please suggest a powerful method which could help me with this problem?

Thank You!

Comment: Sure: flip a coin.  The computer can do that efficiently and repeatedly.

Comment: @whuber thank you for reply. Ok, I flip a coin N times (number of pages) and end up with two groups with almost the same number of pages, but with completely different traffic. 
That is not what I want. What I want is two groups with possibly different number of pages, but with the really close traffic behaviour. Say I have a daily traffic for last 30 days for every single page. I want to end up with two time series which are as closest as possible to each other (without lags considering, only daily difference).

Comment: The randomness guarantees, with astronomically high probability, that the "traffic behavior," however you might define that, will be comparable in the two groups.